# Knowing which button was clicked on the product page in an observer?

Tags: magento2, event-observer

Magento 2.4.6

I added a button to my `addtocart.phtml`. Below the button I added a hidden field, like this:

```
<button type="submit" 
        title="<?= $buttonSampleTitle ?>" 
        class="action primary sample tocart"
        id="product-sample-button">
    <span>
        <?= $buttonSampleTitle ?>
    </span>
</button>
<input type="hidden" id="is-sample" name="is-sample" value="0" />
```

Now I created an observer listening to the `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add` event. Doing so, I can read out the `is-sample` value in the observer like this:

```
$isSample = $observer->getRequest()->getParam('is-sample');
```

The problem is, I need to modify (change name and price) the quote item in the same observer, which doesnt work. It only works when I use the `checkout_cart_product_add_after` event. With that event on the other hand, I can not read the `is-sample` parameter in the observer.

Is there a way to make it work together? Or maybe there is another way of adding a button to my template and knowing it was clicked in the `checkout_cart_product_add_after` event?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still get the request when using `checkout_cart_product_add_after`, it's just not included in the observer params, so you need to include it in your class manually:

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Module\Observer;

class Observer implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface {
    private \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
    ) {
        $this->request = $request;
    }
    
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer): void {
        $isSample = $this->request->getParam('is-sample');
        
        // Rest of code
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, works like a charm! Thanks!